# Tool to find all methods and classes used from a specific assembly in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, .net-assembly

I have a Xamarin.iOS project that references a DLL created from a bindings project.
The bindings project is rather big and "hacky". I want to recreate the bindings project but this time start with the minimum amount of methods and classes needed, instead of binding everything and then fight my way through typos and other issues. I incrementally want to add new stuff but I want to have everything in that I currently use.
Is there a way in Visual Studio (or a tool) that scans a solution and prints out all:

- classes used from the referenced assembly
- all methods and properties used from these classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what the *managed* linker does :-) It removes everything that's not being used.

So you could:

a) enable **Link all assemblies** (or at least make sure binding.dll is linked when build against your application);

b) use a tool to show everything inside your binding.dll

e.g. **IL Spy** on Windows or Xamarin's Studio Assembly Browser

> then fight my way through typos and other issues

I **strongly** suggest you to (now or later) create a [binding unit test project](http://blog.xamarin.com/producing-better-bindings-for-xamarin.ios-and-xamarin.mac/). That will find 99% of the typos and other common mistakes in your bindings. You'll save a lot of time and it will make updating your bindings a lot easier.

Comment: We tried your instructions above, but IL Spy always shows all methods of the binding lib, even the ones we don't use at all. We opened the DLL that is inside the generated app bundle.

Comment: Two potential issues. (1) you did **not** enable **Link all assemblies** so nothing was removed *or* (2) you opened the .dll from the directory where the .app is located (not the one inside the .app). You can compare the size of both assemblies (original and linked) and they **should** differ.