# Xamarin Studio: Show all classes and class members used in a project

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have been told that Visual Studio has a feature that shows you all the classes and class members you used in your solution.  Is there a way to do something similar with a Xamarin.iOS app in Xamarin Studio?  Or maybe a clever command line utility?

Comment: Do you mean your own classes/members or the framework classes/members. If the first one, then you should check out View -> Assembly Browser. If the second, I don't think there is something like that.

Comment: @Jivko, yeah, I was hoping for the latter.  I want to see what framework members we're using in the project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to find all methods and classes used from a specific assembly in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448210/tool-to-find-all-methods-and-classes-used-from-a-specific-assembly-in-net)